# Is it safe to disable the stop/start system?

Tags: battery, charging

I want to permanently disable the **stop/start feature** on my Skoda Octavia Mk3 (based on VW).

<sub>TL:DR; The implementation is faulty. Suppose I want to pass a parked car, and slow down for a car coming the other way. I might still be moving, and in gear (auto) yet the engine cuts out, the steering loses power, and I can't complete the manoeuvre. I'd go so far as to say it is dangerous. But you have to disable the system every time you start the car, and I do not always remember. Anyway I can and do switch off the engine when it is not needed.</sub>

VW claims it is not possible to disable the system but I found there is a connector from one of the battery posts which monitors the state of the battery, to check if there is enough power to run the lighting and aircon, and restart the engine. If disconnected, the stop/start system does not work.

The [post I found](https://www.vwroc.com/forums/topic/20951-disable-start-stopwithout-recoding/) says

> I have a very good friend who is a master tech at VW and a bit of a car genius too........he did it without me knowing! Its a simple little plug and if he tells me that its only there to inform the start stop function then I absolutely trust him.

[image]

I do not want to try this if it will cause something bad. So, my question is:

- If I disconnect will it affect the normal charging of the battery, or anything else?

Comment: Start/stop should only come into play when the vehicle is *COMPLETELY* stopped. Engine should stop when the vehicle is stopped and the foot is still on the brake, then restart when you take your foot off the brake. Is there an ongoing issue with all VW/Skodas where it doesn't?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the vehicle has not even stopped. In the (now linked) thread some others confirm that it happens at inappropriate times... E.g. *"As when driven various Auto's with Stop/Start it bordered on dangerious when the car cuts out while waiting in a juntion etc."* And *"I've always thought that it prematurely cuts the engine off and it has frustrated me many times in the past."*

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I guess you are talking about automatic transmission? I've only driven a manual with stop-start a few times (in the UK) but AFAIK the engine only stops when the gear is in neutral and the clutch pedal is up. At red lights etc, pressing the clutch to select a gear restarts the engine. Holding the clutch down keeps the engine running. Of course people do ride the brake pedal when stopped on level ground, but the "correct" procedure (which is necessary for hill starts anyway) is to use the handbrake and have both feet off the pedals.

Comment: As long as what's said is accurate, I'd be plying VAG for some kind of fix or have them disable it. Yah, does not sound safe. And @alephzero ... you're right, only autos with it I've driven. Still, the vehicle should be stopped when it's activated. If it's stopping midstream, there's a huge safety issue there.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes it is DSG auto. An out-of-warranty vehicle will need £££ to fix/correct at a main agent. I have twice taken it to the franchise (about other problems asked here too) and both times they were unable to understand and convey to the mechanic. It was all a total waste of time and I don't suppose this would be different.

Comment: ...but my question is not if the faulty system is unsafe: it is whether disabling it in this way will affect the battery charging, or anything else.

Comment: I realize that, @WeatherVane ... which is why these are comments. I'm sure you realize, a safety issue, no matter how old the vehicle, is still the issue of the manufacturer. Take for instance the Takata airbag SNAFU which Honda had to deal with ... they are still trying to contact me about replacing the airbag in my 2003 Civic which has long since been destroyed (as well as I had already had the airbag done on it). Just saying, if it's a safety issue, the manufacturer should be taking care of it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm glad you survived :) Thanks I can at least ask at the main dealer if there are any issues.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I absolutely agree the vehicle should be stopped when it activates. But (after 50 years driving only manual tranmissions) I would never ever consider "freewheeling" out of gear with the clutch pedal up, so that's not very relevant in practice. I quickly adapted to just keeping the clutch down in situation where I didn't want the engine to stop - e.g. when forced to stop before turning onto a busy road at a junction with no traffic lights.

Comment: FWIW, it's pretty easy to permanently disable the start-stop-system on VAG cars with software like VCDS. Look around on Facebook for local enthusiast groups and you'll probably find someone who can do that for you.

Comment: @towe thanks for the advice. I need to be able to re-enable it for it the government's statutory mechanical fitness & safety test (MOT). I read somewhere that the Euro 6 emissions figure takes into account the stop-start system, and disabling it might breach that and cause a theoretical 'fail'.

Comment: I think it's also possible to make the "disable SS system" button remember its last setting. That may suffice for your MOT.